# How can I delete my Google Wave account?

Tags: google-wave, google-accounts

I would like to delete my Google Wave account. I just don't want to have anything to do with Google Wave any more, but I want to keep my existing Google account (Gmail, Docs, etc).

Comment: Off-Topic , This may help  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/wave/thread?tid=56eae83bd89981bb&hl=en

Comment: FAQ: [SuperUser] is not about: websites or web services like [Google Wave].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will automatically delete itself after nine months of inactivity. Aside from that, I don't believe they have implemented an easy/convenient way to delete your Wave account.

Comment: From what I could find, it _might_ delete its self after nine months of inactivity. Are you positive that this is a definite way to get rid of Google Wave?

Comment: I can't speak from personal experience; I've used mine on a regular basis. I based my response on the Google Wave Privacy page.
http://wave.google.com/privacy.html